# Help with integration involving exponential

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am trying to solve an equation in the book Digital Image Processing, but I am stuck in the steps in between the formula and solution. Here's the equation, the last line is the solution.

Sorry it's in image format since I was having difficulty with the equation writing here.

[image]

Comment: Do you know that $sin(A)=\frac{1}{2j}(e^{jA}-e^{-jA})$ in a exponential form?

Comment: @Don, yes, but I need help with that exactly, what's the manipulation to get to the solution using that (Euler's rule, right?). I haven't done calculus in a long while.

Comment: So you know the answer to be the last entry in the line. Is it given?

Comment: Lets try to rewrite $1$ as $e^{j\pi uat}*e^{-j\pi uat}$ this becomes a little bit familiar to $sin(A)$. Maybe then try to pull out common exponential term. And it does I think, or do you want me to submit the answer?

Comment: Do you see it? If you need I can submit the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from: $-\frac{T}{j2\pi ua}(e^{-j2\pi ua}-1)=-\frac{T}{j2\pi ua}(e^{-j2\pi ua}-e^{-j\pi ua}e^{j\pi ua})=-\frac{T}{j2\pi ua}(e^{-j\pi ua}-e^{j\pi ua})e^{-j\pi ua}=\frac{T}{j2\pi ua}(-e^{-j\pi ua}+e^{j\pi ua})e^{-j\pi ua}=\frac{T}{\pi ua}sin(\pi ua)e^{-j\pi ua}$

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It's a clever trick with 1. Thanks again.